# IOS application - intercept incoming calls and redirect them to voice mail

Tags: ios

Is there a way to intercept incoming calls and redirect them to voice mail?

Comment: Yes, but only the user can do it.  You are not allowed to.

Comment: Your latest questions seem to be very hard to answer correctly if you do not specify your target market. In other words, please tell us if a jailbroken device solution is acceptable either by tagging or mentioning it in your question.

Comment: Only when the device is jailbroken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to interact with the Phone application from your application.