# Intercepting incoming calls on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, incoming-call

I would like to write software for my iPhone that intercepts incoming calls, and requires that the caller press "1" to proceed with the call. (This is for fighting telemarketers.)

I would prefer to write the software myself, and not install an app like Hiya.

I have a regular phone number assigned by my carrier (no fancy Google Voice or VOIP stuff), and I use the standard "Phone" app. My phone is not jail-broken.

**What's the simplest way to intercept an incoming call to the standard "Phone" app?**

(This is inspired by the [Jolly Roger Telephone Company](http://www.jollyrogertelco.com/) anti-telemarketer bot.)

Note: Some old threads ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026233/ios-application-intercept-incoming-calls-and-redirect-them-to-voice-mail), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119474/intercept-incoming-call-ios-sdk-non-jailbreak)) say it's impossible, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669421/how-to-intercept-messages-sent-from-callkit-incoming-call-screen) thread mentions iOS 10's "CallKit" framework, but it seems it's geared more toward VOIP apps. So it seems like it might be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Impossible with public APIs meant for the App Store.

Comment: @rmaddy, are there private APIs that I could use if I don't intend to host my app on the App Store?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the private APIs

Comment: I always wonder how spam detection apps (calls blacklist etc) get the number of incoming calls...

Comment: @ConvexMartian were you able to get incoming calls phone number using CallKit? I need to do that for "real calls", not VOIP, do you know if it's ok for my use case? It's unclear to me

Comment: @Paolo, I gave up on this project so I didn't try CallKit, sorry!

Comment: @ConvexMartian I need a such thing. If you are still interested too, I'd gladly offer a generous bounty for that, sponsoring your question. Let me know.

Comment: @Paolo I use one "spam detection" app and all this one does is create a group under contacts with all known spam numbers. Does it exist other solutions I would love to know about it.

Comment: I highly doubt it being impossible, there are numerous apps now that can block robocallers. e.g. [RoboKiller](https://www.robokiller.com/), [Truecaller](https://www.truecaller.com/)

Comment: Blocking calls is offered by the CallKit API, but it doesn't work as you would expect. Instead of Apple sharing call data with you, you need to sync a list of contacts through CallKit extension with iOS, and iOS will block those numbers on your behalf.